# Merge PR by Github action if review was approved by a user

Tags: github, pull-request, github-actions

Is it possible to configure Github actions workflow to merge pull request if it was approved (submitted review with `approve` keyword) by one of the users (static fixed list, which can be written in workflow config file)? I tried to find it in documentation: https://help.github.com/en/articles/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#on
- I suppose I can use `on: [pull_request_review]` trigger for action, but documentation didn't mention how to access event payload in action `yaml` file, where I need to extract reviewer login from this payload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this in https://help.github.com/en/articles/virtual-environments-for-github-actions#filesystems-on-github-hosted-machines:

> `workflow/event.json`: The `POST` payload of the webhook event that triggered the workflow. GitHub rewrites this each time an action executes to isolate file content between actions. Use the `GITHUB_EVENT_PATH` environment variable to access this file.

So the next step will be figuring out how to parse a JSON file and extract some data that a *later* step can use. For that, looking at [GitHub's `setup-dotnet` action](https://github.com/actions/setup-dotnet) might prove useful. In [line 62 of `installer.ts`](https://github.com/actions/setup-dotnet/blob/a2db70294c800f14593a400f4a1dc16ff5a73a36/src/installer.ts#L62), they call a function called `core.exportVariable`, which as you can see [here](https://github.com/actions/setup-dotnet/issues/33), causes `##[set-env name=NAME;]value` to be printed in the action's output. I've personally verified that this causes the environment variable called `NAME` to automatically be present in later steps of the same workflow job.

Now, I don't yet know if you can simply do `echo "##[set-env name=NAME;]$VALUE"` in a `run` step of a GitHub workflow and have that work; it's possible that you'll have to write a custom action in Typescript to get access to `core.exportVariable`. But once you have parsed the JSON, that would be one way of passing that information on to later steps in your job.

Comment: I just thought of a much simpler approach: write a Bash script (or PowerShell script if you're on Windows) which will parse the JSON file and decide whether to approve the pull request. If the pull request should be approved, exit with a 0 exit code. If not, exit with a non-zero exit code, which will cause the workflow to stop in a failed state.

Comment: Thanks, it's also working for Docker actions, Github provides event JSON payload at `GITHUB_EVENT_PATH` inside Docker container

Answer (score 1):

In addition of [rmunn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2314532/rmunn)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57830706/6309), you might also want to protect your branch:

> ### [GitHub Actions: Prevent GitHub Actions from approving pull requests](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-01-14-github-actions-prevent-github-actions-from-approving-pull-requests/) (2022, 14th Jan.)

> We have introduced a new policy setting that controls whether GitHub Actions can approve pull requests.
> This protects against a user using Actions to satisfy the "Required approvals" branch protection requirement and merging a change that was not reviewed by another user.
>
> To prevent breaking existing workflows, `Allow GitHub Actions reviews to count towards required approval` is enabled by default.
> However, an organization admin can disable it under the organization's Actions settings.
>
> [image: image -- https://i2.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/185122/149253738-114b65d9-9a65-4bfd-b379-bce03ca363e1.png?ssl=1]

That way, you are sure approvals were made exclusively by *users*, not by other actions.